# Why my js function is not working for increase size?

Tags: javascript

I made a function to increase font size by click on button.

```
    <body>
    <p id="demo">1. New Journey Started, Best of Luck.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.fontsize = "x-large";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Please help to me to know what's the problem?

Comment: `.style.fontsize` -> `.style.fontSize`

Comment: Duplicate of: [Use of hyphenated property keys for element.style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68802758)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font size should be in camel case:

```
function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = "x-large";
        }
```